# how to convert a panda dataframe column containing string object to a numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-preprocessing

please i'am working on a project and i have to do some data preprocessing
i have a dataframe that looks like this (this is just an example for simplification

```
index | pixels 
0     | 10 20 30 40 
1     | 11 12 13 14
```

and I want to convert it to a np array of shape (2,2,2,1)
the type of the pixels column is object
is there any solution to do that without loops cause I have a 28k rows data frame with big images ?
i have tried looping but it takes so long to execute on my machine

Comment: here the reshape (2,2,2,1) works because you have 2 rows, but what is the final output you want with 28K rows?

Comment: This dataframe is confusing. What type of data is the `pixels` column? are those arrays? lists? strings?

Comment: A pandas display (much less a simplification) doesn't tell us much about the elements of a column, whether they be strings, lists or arrays.  `arr=df.to_numpy()` may be more informative.  But strings to numpy is often awkward.  `pandas` may have a way of "exploding" a column into multiple columns.

Comment: @Ben.T for a dataframe with 28k rows and each row have a string of let's say 25 numbers, i want to get a np array of shape (28k,5,5,1)

Comment: @HenryEcker the `pixels` is a string of numbers separated by 1 space each number represents one pixel like that : "10 20 30 40" , i hope its more clear like this

Comment: @hpaulj i am sorry if my representation was not clear enough but yeah like you said the `pixels` column is of type string and changing this to be a np array is very cofusing to me ! i dont know if its just because i am a begginer or because i dont get something right in my mind !! anyway thank you for the help really apreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) + [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas-series-astype) + [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html#pandas-series-to-numpy) + [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy-ndarray-reshape):

```
a = (
    df['pixels'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
        .astype(int).to_numpy()
        .reshape((2, 2, 2, 1))
)
```

`a`:

```
[[[[10]
   [20]]

  [[30]
   [40]]]


 [[[11]
   [12]]

  [[13]
   [14]]]]
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'pixels': ['10 20 30 40', '11 12 13 14']})

a = (
    df['pixels'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
        .astype(int).to_numpy()
        .reshape((2, 2, 2, 1))
)
print(a)
```